# DocumentProperty.Name in Office 16.27 for Mac generates Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, macos

I'm trying to read Office document properties with VBA.

I get an error with DocumentProperty.Name with Office for Mac. This appears to be a change in version 16.27 (or so).

The code works on Windows.

On Mac the same error occurs for Word, Excel and PowerPoint (taking into account the ActiveDocument/Workbook/Presentation difference).

```
Sub ListDocProps()

 Dim prop As DocumentProperty
 Dim msg As String

 For Each prop In ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties
  msg = msg & prop.Name

  On Error Resume Next
   msg = msg & prop.Value
 Next

 MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

I was expecting to see the property names, but I get the error message:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that Microsoft thinks this was a bug. In a more recent build of Office, Version 16.29 (19081902), the problem has disappeared.

Thanks for reading,
Sandy